# Ionic 2 page as npm package

Tags: npm, ionic2

I'm trying to reuse some Ionic 2 pages in multiple apps, is there any way I can pack them into an npm module or something like that?

I tried to put everything(scss,html and ts) into a package and both importing the page or the module with the page makes it compile but it won't find the HTMl file.

It'll spit the following error on opening the app

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load listing.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load listing.html
```

Kind regards